# How to send all URLs with the same base URL to that base URL with a large parameter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new to mod_rewrite thing.

Here is what I want to do.
In my local webserver I have a test directory with a welcome.php
So the route is

```
http://localhost/test_stuff/welcome.php
```

I want a rule such that

http://localhost/test_stuff/{anything-that-can-come-here}

Gets turn into

http://localhost/test_stuff/welcome.php?rest={anything-that-can-come-here}

So, for example, an addresses like this

```
http://localhost/test_stuff/some/other/stufff?from=a&to=b
```

turns into addresses like this

```
http://localhost/test_stuff/welcome.php?rest=some/other/stufff?from=a&to=b
```

So I went to my virtual host configuration and added these two lines

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/api_test/(*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/api_test/welcome.php?rest=$1
```

However I can't restart the apache due to the regular expression not being compilable.

How can I write a regular expression to get my intended effect?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempted rules; could take you please try following Rules. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Condition to check THE_REQUEST variable and match values as per requirement here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUST} \s/([^/]*)/([^?]*)\?(\S+)\s [NC]
##Rewriting to welcome.php as per requirement with variables.
RewriteRule ^ %1/welcome.php?rest=%2%3 [L]
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can try it but I allready see something that doesn't convince me. The example is to show something generic. I literraly want anyting that comes after the test_stuff/ to be after the rest=. I will modify my question to make this clearer

Comment: @aarelovich, could you please give more clear samples, I could edit my answer then, cheers

Comment: I modified the question to see if you can understand better. Thanks

Comment: @aarelovich, only appending query string is allowed, more than one query string is not allowed imho so URL `http://localhost/test_stuff/welcome.php?rest=some/other/stufff?from=a&to=b` should be Little different
.

Comment: So there is now way to treat everything that comes after test_stuff as a single group in ther regular expression? I don't understand.

Comment: @aarelovich, it creates 2 groups and passing it accordingly into rewrite rule, could you please try following once and let me know how it goes 

Comment: Ohh sorry. I did try it. It gave me a Bad Request error in the server.

Comment: @aarelovich, could you please do let me know here sample url which you are hitting and getting errors please.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I solved my need with an Alias instead of using mod rewrite. Thank you